# Why does Windows FORFILES with option /D -10 not find files last modified within last 10 days?

Tags: windows, cmd, forfiles

The following command line lists **every** `.JS` file in the current directory and all subfolders, not just the files last modified in the previous 10 days as expected by me.

```
FORFILES /S /D -10 /M *.js /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

Whereas this command lists only the `.JS` files modified on or after 2/20/2022.

```
FORFILES /S /D 2/20/2022 /M *.js /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

Any ideas why using the option `/D -10` doesn't result in the expected output?

Comment: Because your expectations are wrong. `/D -10` means all files modified *earlier*  than 10 days ago ...  Citing the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles) *"[...] earlier than or equal to (-) the current date minus the number of days specified."*

Comment: While `/d +10` means "files that will be modified next week or later". What does `forfiles` know, that I don't? I'd really like to have word with the developer...

Comment: @Stephan Haha, thought the same thing when reading the docs ... In fact it looks like `forfiles` sadly doesn't support something like "modified within the last 10 days"  -- which would be my expected (and a more reasonable) behaviour for `/D +10` -- other than via using a specific date ...

Comment: When I use `FORFILES /?`, the /D parameter indicates that dates should be in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Does `FORFILES` use the system regional settings? If so, coding this could be a problem if it is ever run on a system with different regional settings.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses! @derpirscher was correct.  I see that now after reading the help output more closely.  As mentioned, I was expecting a quick way to see files modified in the last # days without doing the math in my head and entering a spec'd date.  (i know that's lazy, but).  Anyway I wrote a quick batch using robocopy to help me with this.

Comment: Regarding /d +x, the spec was written badly and some programmer implemented it literally. But there are versions of forfiles exe out there where it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The execution of `forfiles /?` in a command prompt window to show the usage help results on Windows with language **English US**, but with region/country/format **German (Austria)** configured for the user account, for option `/D` in the output:

> Selects files with a last modified date greater than or equal to (+), or less than or equal to (-), the specified date using the "dd.MM.yyyy" format; or selects files with a last modified date greater than or equal to (+) the current date plus "dd" days, or less than or equal to (-) the current date minus "dd" days. A valid "dd" number of days can be any number in the range of 0 - 32768. "+" is taken as default sign if not specified.

**The date format is region dependent.**

`dd.MM.yyyy` means:

1. Day in month with two digits, i.e. `01` to `31`.
2. A dot is the separator between day in month and month.
3. Month with two digits, i.e. `01` to `12`.
4. A dot is the separator between month and year.
5. Year with century with four digits like `2022`.

The specification of a date in international date format `yyyy-MM-dd` results on my PC in the error message:

> ERROR: Invalid date specified.
> Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.

**Some examples for a better understanding:**

```
forfiles /D 13.08.2021
forfiles /D +13.08.2021
```

This outputs all file system entries (file and directory names) with last modification date **newer** (greater than) **or equal** August 13<sup>th</sup>, 2021.

```
forfiles /D -13.08.2021
```

This outputs all file system entries (file and directory names) with last modification date **older** (less than) **or equal** August 13<sup>th</sup>, 2021.

```
forfiles /D -10
```

This outputs all file system entries (file and directory names) with last modification date **older** (less than) **or equal** February 16<sup>th</sup>, 2022 on current date being February 26<sup>th</sup>, 2022 (`26.02.2022`).

```
forfiles /D 10
forfiles /D +10
```

This outputs all file system entries (file and directory names) with last modification date **newer** (greater than) **or equal** March 08<sup>th</sup>, 2022 on current date being February 26<sup>th</sup>, 2022 (`26.02.2022`). Such a date specification does not make much sense in most cases if the current date is correct and so files/folders with a future date do most likely not exist at all. So such a date specification results usually in the error message:

> ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.

**Some more hints:**

1. The file/folder names are always output enclosed in `"` which is important to know on using for example in a batch file:

   ```
   @echo off
   echo The following files are older than nine days:
   echo/
   for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /D -10 2^>nul') do if not exist "%%~I\" echo     %%I
   ```
2. The file/folder names are never output with path even on using option `/S`.
   So capturing the output of [forfiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles) using `for /F` for further processing the files/folders more efficient with `cmd.exe` instead of using the **FORFILES** option `/C` makes no sense on using option `/S` to search also in subdirectories of the current directory respectively the directory specified with **FORFILES** option `/P`.
3. The usage of **FORFILES** without option `/D` makes never sense as in this case it is always more efficient and definitely better to use the internal command [for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for) of the **Windows Command Processor** [cmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd).
4. `forfiles.exe` does by default not exist on Windows XP and older Windows client versions. `forfiles.exe` in Windows system32 directory of Windows Server 2003 can be copied to the Windows system32 directory of a PC with Windows XP. Windows Server 2003 uses the same kernel as Windows XP.
   By the way: `choice.exe` and `robocopy.exe` in Windows system32 directory of Windows Server 2003 can be also copied to Windows system32 directory of Windows XP as not existing by default on Windows XP too.

PS: A directory is for file systems like NTFS, FAT12, FAT16, FAT32, exFAT a file with the attribute `d`.